# passing key events from main window to iframe using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to pass key events [keydown, keyup] triggered on main window to inner iframe, with no luck; both the pages [page loaded in main window & page loaded in iframe] are from same domain; below is the code I tried.

```
$(document.body).on('keyup keydown', function (event) {
    $($('#innerIframe')[0].contentWindow.document).trigger(event);
});
```

Can you point what I am missing/doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in a different way, Instead of passing/forwarding key events from main window to inner iframe, I updated the event listener binding code, in iframe as below

```
$(document).add($(parent.document)).on('keyup keydown', function (event) {
    // process event
});
```

Comment: Better semantics: $([document, parent.document]).on('keyup...